# How to add missing paragraph into HTML code?

Tags: python, regexp-replace

I would like to add a missing paragraph tag `<p></p>` in a broken HTML code.

Example: this is my broken HTML code:

```html
<strong>My Headline</strong>
This text has a missing paragraph
<strong>Some more text <a href="#">maybe with a link</a></strong>
<p>this one is right</p>
```

I'd like to add the missing paragraph tags like this:

```html
<p>
  <strong>My Headline</strong>
</p>
<p>
  This text has a missing paragraph
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Some more text <a href="#">maybe with a link</a></strong>
</p>
<p>this one is right</p>
```

What would be the best solution to fix this problem using Python3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods of the `str` class for that.

Something like this:

```py
>>> s = '''<strong>My Headline</strong>
... This text has a missing paragraph
... <strong>Some more text <a href="#">maybe with a link</a></strong>
... <p>this one is right</p>'''
>>> 
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     print(f'<p>{line}</p>' if not line.startswith('<p>') else line)
... 
<p><strong>My Headline</strong></p>
<p>This text has a missing paragraph</p>
<p><strong>Some more text <a href="#">maybe with a link</a></strong></p>
<p>this one is right</p>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read it from the html file, try this:

```
with open("example.html", "r")as old, open("new.html", "w") as new:

    for line in old:
        if line.strip().startswith("<p>"):
            new.write(line)
        else:
            new.write("<p>\n" + line + "</p>\n")
```